# Temporarily Disable/Reenable YouCompleteMe Plugin

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me, plugin-syntastic

Is there a way to temporarily disable/reenable the YouCompleteMe Plugin for vim? Syntastic has a nice way of doing so with the SyntasticToggleMode command (useful for when I know I'm writing code that won't compile and just don't want to see error messages at the moment).

I tried writing a quick Vim function that toggles the `g:ycm_show_diagnostics_ui` variable but it doesn't seem to work as I'd like even though the value of the variable changes.

Note: this works statically (i.e. if I set the `g:ycm_show_diagnostics_ui` variable to zero in my vimrc but doesn't work dynamically).

Comment: After you've sourced your plugins YCM is loaded. The only way to disable it to my knowledge would have to be a feature of YCM itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you toggle the value of `g:ycm_show_diagnostics_ui`, run `:YcmRestartServer` and then reload the file with `:e`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my toggle for turning off diagnostics and the completion menu:

```
"Toggle YouCompleteMe on and off with F3
function Toggle_ycm()
    if g:ycm_show_diagnostics_ui == 0
        let g:ycm_auto_trigger = 1
        let g:ycm_show_diagnostics_ui = 1
        :YcmRestartServer
        :e
        :echo "YCM on"
    elseif g:ycm_show_diagnostics_ui == 1
        let g:ycm_auto_trigger = 0
        let g:ycm_show_diagnostics_ui = 0
        :YcmRestartServer
        :e
        :echo "YCM off"
    endif
endfunction
map <F3> :call Toggle_ycm() <CR>
```

Even when I have YCM turned on, I don't want the cursor hover info popping up automatically, so I have a toggle set up for that as well. It still works even when the above toggle is off.

```
" turn off automatic YouCompleteMe cursor hover info
let g:ycm_auto_hover = ''

" toggle language hover info with F4
map <F4> <plug>(YCMHover)
```